# can you give me an example of that will echo you two datas but from different tables?

Tags: pdo

The problem of my code is that when I use this: 
`$user->data()`
 it only get the data on my user, and then I try to do a function like this:

`public function getId() {
$sqlId = "SELECT id FROM user2_tbl"; (2nd table)
}`

(it is suppose to get the ID on the other table)

then I try to do that function and return it. but when i call it on like this:

```
<?php echo escape($user->dataId()->id); ?>
```

abd it errors this: **Trying to get property of non-object**

Answer (score 0):

try using INNER JOIN for you to connect the two of your tables.